# Using pointer in function to get value from the input

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

i wanted to get value from the input in Triangle struct that i declared by using  read(&g)
However i'm getting confused in pointers when i'm using sub-function

```
typedef struct {
int a,b,c;
}Triangle;

void read(Triangle *pointer)
{
printf("Enter the sides of triangle:\n");
int x,y,z;
(*pointer).a = x;
(*pointer).b = y;
(*pointer).c = z;
scanf("%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z);
}


int main()
{
Triangle g;
read(&g);
printf("%d ",g.a);
printf("%d ",g.b);
printf("%d ",g.c);
}
```

Comment: Your `read` function assigns the values before you read them, so they're undefined in your structure. What do you mean by, *I'm getting confused in pointers*?

Comment: As a note, rather than `(*pointer).a = x` you can just use `pointer->a = x` (but, as lurker said, do this *after* your `scanf` call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your `read` function by using `scanf` to read *directly* into the member variables. (Also, "pointer" is not really a good name for a pointer variable). Here's a more succinct version:

```c
void read(Triangle *pT)
{
    printf("Enter the sides of triangle:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &(pT->a), &(pT->b), &(pT->c));
}
```

Note: For a `struct` variable itself, you can use the `.` operator to access a member (like `g.a` in your `main`); for a *pointer* to that `struct` variable, you can use the `->` operator to access that member (as with `pT->a` in my code). As `scanf` wants the *address* of each member, you add the `&` operator - the brackets make it clear exactly what address you want.